# How reliable is execution of batch jobs?

Tags: schedulebatch

The requirement is to Update a picklist field, and send an email after 3 minutes of creating a record.

One Option is to use time based workflow rules. But these are scheduled as a batch & are executed within 60 minutes of triggering 1st event.

Another option is to write a batch job that runs every one minute.

As batch jobs also scheduled in another queue, can execution of batch jobs be relied upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't guarantee when batch or scheduled class execution will occur, it is based on availability of resources on your Salesforce pod.

From the documentation :

> Salesforce schedules the class for execution at the specified time.
>   Actual execution may be delayed based on service availability.

There is also a really good whitepaper '**Asynchronous Processing in Force com**' at https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com that explains lots of the detail behind how requests are queued.